# Protractor tests running on Windows

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm struggling already a while to force Protractor tests running stable on windows. The same tests are working perfectly fine on Linux environment but on Windows sporadically occurs

> Failed: Angular could not be found on the page
>   http://localhost:2000/index.html#/app : angular never provided
>   resumeBootstrap

I already applied several treatments which I found by googling:

```
browser.executeScript () ->  window.name = "NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!"
```

so protractor kinda should wait till angular will be bootstrapped.

Apart from that there was a solution to say explicitly to protractor to wait for angular:

```
browser.waitForAngular()
```

But still no luck.

I thought maybe for some cases windows can be slow to render a page for protractor and increased page timeout to 30 seconds, but it didn't help as well.

By the way I'm using protractor 2.1, updated yesterday to this version with a hope that this problem will be finally solved there.

Any suggestions what else could be an issue?

protractor.conf is:

```
exports.config = {
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:6518/",
    specs: ["./e2e/**/*.coffee"],
    allScriptsTimeout: 30000,
    getPageTimeout: 30000,
    capabilities: {
        "browserName": (process.env.KARMA_BROWSER || "Firefox").toLowerCase()
    },
    framework: "jasmine",
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000
    },
    onPrepareCommon: function(customiseDSL) {
        addLibraries({
            "_": "lodash",
            requestify: "requestify"
        });
        addJQueryLocator();

        var reporters = require('jasmine-reporters');

        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new reporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
            savePath: 'build/test-results',
            consolidateAll: false
        }));

        customiseDSL();

        Browser.open();
        Browser.setDefaultSize();

        browser.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(30000);

        function addLibraries(libraries) {
            for(var key in libraries) {
                global[key] = require(libraries[key]);
            }
        }

        function addJQueryLocator() {
            By.addLocator("$", function() {
                var selector = arguments[0];
                var using = arguments[1] || document;
                var results = $(using).find(selector);
                var matches = [];
                if (!$.isArray(results)) {
                    matches.push(results.get(0));
                } else {
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
                        matches.push(results[i][0]);
                    }
                }
                return matches; // Return the whole array for webdriver.findElements.
            });
        }
    }
};
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/libs/css/components.css" media="screen,print"/>
</head>

<body ng-app="Applications">
<div ui-view></div>

<script src="dist/libs/js/components.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you should update selenium-webdriver and protractor.This may help you.

Comment: Hi Riyaj, as I mentioned I'm using protractor 2.1 - which is the newest one. And web-driver is the part of protractor distribution "node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager"

Comment: Can you  please share snippet of protractor.js  and index.html ?

Comment: Sure, I've updated the posted question. Please have a look

Comment: First thing are you want to test angular or coffee-script ? In configuration  you mention "specs: ["./e2e/**/*.coffee"]" path.  Please check the whether the angular.js and its dependency  lib is included or not? Also   update the capabilities: {
        "browserName": (process.env.KARMA_BROWSER || "chrome").toLowerCase()
    },  This happened because either angular lib is not found or there is no angular script is loaded for test.

Comment: First of all, as a reminder - these test are working on Linux and *sporadically* fails on Windows, 99% of them are successfully pasted and 1% are failing. Coffee-script is a language on which tests are written, you can use any language for that TypeScript of whatever. Angular.js is included in html and it is not required to be a dependency in protractor.conf